# How do I disable Xcode static analysis (Clang) messages?

Tags: xcode, clang, warnings

I'd like my Xcode project to go through a Build And Analyze step without generating any errors, warnings, or static analysis messages. A problem with this is that my project includes libraries that generate (possibly innocuous) warnings and static analysis messages.

I can't find a way to disable specific Clang warnings so that "my" code builds with zero issues. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't able to find any way to do this, and filed a bug against Clang. The team seems to want to add this functionality, but it's not there yet.

The bug is: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=7296

Also, one can use [a `__clang_analyzer__` macro](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/faq.html#exclude_code) to ifdef out any code that one doesn't want Clang to process.

Comment: If you're going to answer your own question, could you at least link to the doc or give an example of your **clang_analyzer** macro?

Comment: The answer has a link to the info, which was all I knew. But, I just googled it for you, so here's a little bit more info on the __clang_analyzer__ macro. It's pretty straightforward. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#analyzer_diagnositics

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't post it in a lmgtfy link :) Thanks Khakionion, this is really useful stuff. Are you on the LLVM team at Apple? I have a line of communication with one of the frontend compiler team re: adding covariance support, was wondering if it would be worth creating a SO post to see what others think.

Comment: Nope, I work on the iOS SDK. The issue came about back when I was working at a game company using Box2D. We didn't want to change any library code, but the code created analyzer issues. The macro is nice to have, but wouldn't have solved our particular problem due to coding policies.

Answer (score -1):

The Build and Analyze step ***is*** clang - thats the "analyze" part. It wouldn't make sense to analyze your code and not have clang tell you about issues it find. That's like going to a car wash and telling them not to touch the car.

From talking to the guy that wrote clang at WWDC, it is extremely unlikely that anything it identifies as an issue is actually not. If you think you have some examples of code that works fine but clang complains, please file a [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com) with example code so Apple can fix that.

You can [disable some compiler warnings](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) through the use of flags, but not all of them are an option.

Comment: I understand the philosophy behind Clang. While I'm no longer on that project (in fact, now I'm working at Apple, lol), this is not a sufficient answer because it was a third-party library whose code we were not going to change due to policy. 

Also, I filed the bug a week after posting this question. :D http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=7296

Comment: If you reached the conclusion on your own that there is no valid solution for your issue, which by working at Apple you would have access to far better information on the matter than the rest of us, it would be nice if you deleted/closed your question so people don't waste effort trying to help you.

Comment: Good point, the truth is that I had forgotten about this question until I was notified of your response. :) I can suppose I can answer this question with information about the pending bug, because that's as much as I know about progress on the issue for now.

Comment: I don't think that's a realistic answer: Clang static analyzer has bugs (very few but still) and can report false positives. This adds distracting noise to the output of Xcode static analysis (even more so in Xcode build server), adding unnecessarily hassle when watching for introduced regressions. Reporting such issues to Apple means it would take at best months before they are fixed.

Comment: its not really the point if your policy excludes making changes to third party code. the warnings in box2d are quite harmless too... dead stores. they are being done to avoid uninitialised variables (even though they are always written to later). it would be nice to turn it off rather than modify 3rd party code.